# Installing Ubuntu 12.10 with Virtualbox -> Not enough storage

Tags: 12.10, windows-7, virtualbox, hard-drive

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 with Virtualbox. I allowed 20GB of space for the virtual computer and when I tried to install it, it said that I don't have enough space, which I have over 100GB. And I really don't want to format my hard drive because that would screw up everything. How can I fix this?

Comment: The complaint is about the 20GB you allocated for your virtual machine, not for the 100GB remaining space in your host file system. **But** 20GB should be more than enough.

Comment: Well now I reinstalled it and allowed 50GB for it and now I got it without any trouble.